# iterating through a collection in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to search for a keyword inside article titles, bodies and tag names using LIKE expresion. Articles and tags are defined using one to many relationship

Here is the code snippet from my class:

```
@Entity
public class Article implements Serializable {

   @Basic(optional = false)
   @NotNull
   @Lob
   @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
   @Column(name = "body", nullable = false, length = 65535)
   private String body;
   @Basic(optional = false)

   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 1, max = 250)
   @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 250)
   private String title;

   @Basic(optional = false)
   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 1, max = 9)
   @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 9)
   private String status;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "articleId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
   private List<Tag> tagList;

   // other attributes and methods
}
```

Also the **Tag** class has a **name** attribute.

I'm having problems searching for the keyword inside tags names. I've tried this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Article a ,IN(a.tagList) tag
            WHERE a.status = :status AND 
            (a.title LIKE :pattern OR a.body LIKE :pattern 
            OR tag.name LIKE :pattern)
```

but it doesn't give proper result; not all articles are shown.

Am I iterating right through the tags with **IN**, or do I need to specify **LEFT JOIN**? Any help will be appreciated.

thx in advance

if anyone will face this kind of a problem, this was the solution that worked fine for my case

```
select distinct a from Article a left join a.tagList tag where a.status = :status and 
(a.title like :pattern or a.body like :pattern or tag.name like :pattern)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>First of all, you're using `in` wrong - it should be in the `where` clause, not part of the `select`. I'm surprised you're not getting an exception</strike>. (**[wrong](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_collection_dec)**: see Mikko's comment).

But in your case, you can't use `in`, since you want to use the `like` operator.

I would try something like this:

```
select a from Article a join a.tagList tag where a.status = :status and 
    (a.title like :pattern or a.body like :pattern or tag.name like :pattern)
```

Comment: He is using IN operator in FROM clause, and it is syntactically correct. JPA 2.0 specification: "An identification variable of a collection member declaration is declared using a special operator, the
reserved identifier IN. The argument to the IN operator is a collection-valued path expression."

Comment: ok thanks for your reply,
with your solution I got the same result as before, after adding distinct and replacing the join with left join Im geting the right result (at least I hope so)

so thanks again

Comment: @Mikko thanks, did not know that. (And "in" is not very googlable).